# Find $f(\Bbb R^2)$ where $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$. What is $f(\Bbb R^2)$?

I know I should take $u = e^x \sin y$ and $v =e^x \cos y$ and try to find a relation but I can't find something

Comment: Do you known what the image of $y\mapsto (\cos y, \sin y)$ is? ($y\in [0,2\pi)$, say).

Answer (score 1):

Either you note that $f(z)=e^z$ and know (or show) that $e^z$ takes all complex values except zero, or you solve explicitly the equations $e^x\cos y=a$ and $e^x\sin y=b$:

These equations give $e^x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and since the real exponential $e^x$ never vanishes you get $a\ne0$ or $b\ne0$. In particular, $x=\log\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

If $a=0$, then you can take for example $y=\pm\pi/2$ depending on the sign of $b$. Otherwise, if $a\ne0$, you have $\tan y=b/a$ and so you can take $y=\arctan (b/a)$.

In other words, $e^z=a+ib$ has a solution $z$ if and only if $a\ne0$ or $b\ne0$. Hence, $f(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** In polar coordinates, which we denote by $(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)_p$, we see that $$f(x, y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y) = (e^x, y)_p .$$

> Now, $e^x$ takes on every positive value and $y$ takes on every real value, and the only point that cannot be represented by such a pair (again, in polar coordinates) is the origin, $(0, 0)$. Hence, $f(\Bbb R^2) = \Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$.